# What does "mappedfile" parameter in JspServlet stand for?

Tags: jsp, tomcat, servlets

Im reading https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jasper-howto.html

There is parameter :

> **mappedfile** - Should we generate static content with one print statement per input line, to ease debugging? true or false, default
>   true.

But i can not understand what is the detail usage of this parameter, i've tried to google it but didn't help. Can someone please tell me what it is.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When `mappedfile` is true, container generates "out.print()" for each HTML text line in the JSP file. And when false, the HTML text from multiple lines are concatenated and output in one "out.print()" and that's how it ease debugging.

When `<JspInterceptor mappedFile="true" />` container will generate something like:

```
out.write("<!DOCTYPE html>\r\n");
out.write("<html>\r\n");
out.write("<head>\r\n");
out.write("<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\">\r\n");
out.write("<title>Test</title>\r\n");
out.write("</head>\r\n");
```

And when `<JspInterceptor mappedFile="false" />` something like this:

```
out.write("<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\"><title>Index</title></head>");
```

Older version of `tomcat (3,4)` have this option by default `false` and newer version starting from tomcat 5 have this option default `true`.