# What is purpose of <init-param>mappedfile</init-param> in JspServlet in web.xml?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, web.xml

What is purpose of 'mappedfile' init-param in JspServlet in web.xml?

```
<servlet>
 <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class>
<init-param>
  <param-name>fork</param-name>
  <param-value>false</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
  <param-name>xpoweredBy</param-name>
  <param-value>false</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
  <param-name>mappedfile</param-name>
  <param-value>false</param-value>
</init-param>
<load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

What if i set it to 'TRUE'? What will happen if i set it to 'False'?

Note: I need to implement this as a solution to problem in which one of JSP in application is giving error of exceeding the 65535 bytes limit. I need to find whether this will cause any global issue or not if changed to false or true.

Comment: see https://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/7.0.x/config/jsp.html

Comment: *error of exceeding the 65535 bytes* good opportunity to use servlets

Comment: Use SO search: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7495985/byte-limit-exceed-problem-when-reloading-a-jsp-page

Comment: @Azodious: Thanks but it does not explain details about how this change will impact application, now or near future. So i need bit detailed explanation of Same.

Comment: @ScaryWombat: I am not authorized to do that. Thanks for your link. If you have bit detailed information in laymen language. I shall be more thankful to you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is a parameter to tune performance.

The default property values are tuned for development of JSP files at the cost of performance. To maximize performance, set jsp-config properties to these non-default values:

> development - false (as an alternative, set to true and give modificationTestInterval a large value)
>
> **mappedfile - false**
>
> trimSpaces - true
>
> suppressSmap - true
>
> fork - false (on Solaris)
>
> classdebuginfo - false

**mappedFile description:** Should we generate static content with one print statement per input line, to ease debugging? true or false, default true.

Source: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19226-01/820-7693/beatx/index.html

You can look here too: [What does "mappedfile" parameter in JspServlet stand for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37586068/what-does-mappedfile-parameter-in-jspservlet-stand-for)